# image working as a submit button

Tags: html, css, struts

I do some code already written by previous development Team and I came across a code snippt which acts a bit strangely so Please take a look at it and make me understand.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY id="ext-gen6" class=" ext-ie ext-ie6 ext-border-box"
        leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0">
        <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%"
            height="100%">
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD height="85%" vAlign="top" width="80%">
                        <DIV>
                            <TABLE class="allcolors" border="0" width="100%">
                                <TBODY>
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD>
                                            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" borderColor="#6699cc"
                                                cellPadding="0" width="100%" height="685">
                                                <TBODY>
                                                    <TR>
                                                        <TD class="threecolors" vAlign="top">


                                                                        <FORM id="Report1"
                                                                            encType="multipart/form-data"
                                                                            onsubmit="ProgressBar()" method="post"
                                                                            name="Form2"
                                                                            action="/cgfsampling/assignReport.do">

                                                                                <INPUT id="assign" 
                                                                                    src="http://localhost:8080/myProj/images/cation.gif"
                                                                                    type="image" name="" value="" />

                                                                         </FORM>

                                                                     </TD>


                                                    </TR>
                                                </TBODY>
                                            </TABLE>
                                        </TD>
                                    </TR>
                                </TBODY>
                            </TABLE>
                        </DIV>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

so please let me know  why image is working as a submit button

Thnaks,
Vineet

Comment: First, post your code to the readable format.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, OP never mentioned that his code didn't work. He was wondering how the image is acting as a submit button.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran sorry, I read through the question too quickly. I shall delete my comment. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

When the type of an `input` is `image` it acts as a submit button.  Its part of the specification.

> image: A graphical submit button. You must use the src attribute to
>   define the source of the image and the alt attribute to define
>   alternative text. You can use the height and width attributes to
>   define the size of the image in pixels.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Answer (score 0):

**The input type SRC attribute of the component was set to image earlier**.

**Your code**

```
  <INPUT id="assign" src="http://localhost:8080/myProj/images/cation.gif" type="image" name="" value="" />
```

Below code works as a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY id="ext-gen6" class=" ext-ie ext-ie6 ext-border-box"
      leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" marginheight="0"
      marginwidth="0">
<TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%"
       height="100%">
    <TBODY>
    <TR>
        <TD height="85%" vAlign="top" width="80%">
            <DIV>
                <TABLE class="allcolors" border="0" width="100%">
                    <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" borderColor="#6699cc"
                                   cellPadding="0" width="100%" height="685">
                                <TBODY>
                                <TR>
                                    <TD class="threecolors" vAlign="top">


                                        <FORM id="Report1"
                                              encType="multipart/form-data"
                                              onsubmit="ProgressBar()" method="post"
                                              name="Form2"
                                              action="/cgfsampling/assignReport.do">

                                            <INPUT type='submit' id="assign"
                                                    name="" value="Submit" />

                                        </FORM>

                                    </TD>


                                </TR>
                                </TBODY>
                            </TABLE>
```

Comment: I think image would have submitted the form also.

Comment: Well i didn't say it wouldn't submit.. did i ? :).  OP asked why the image is working as a submit button.